# node js mongodb callback not working - The below piece of code works on my Laptop but does not work on another PC

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The below piece of code works on my Laptop but does not work on another PC.
    // connecting to mongodb

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    winston.error('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    winston.info('Connection established to', url);
    database = db;

     var collection= database.collection('events_dashboard');

      collection.findOne({ 
    timestamp_day : deviceTimestamp ,
      machineId : machine.id,
      currentStatus : machine.currentState
  }, function(err, doc){
        winston.info('never came here');

      if(doc == null){
              insertRawEvent(machine,rawCollection);
              updateEvent(machine,0);
      }
  });


}
```

Comment: How it doesn't work? Programmers needs logs, or program output, or something. Every program works, but some of them works unexpectedly

Comment: MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    winston.error('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
  } else {
    winston.info('Connection established to', url);
    database = db;
}

Answer (score 0):

Well did you start mongodb in your PC first? Which is maybe automatically started in your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

After thoroughly comparing the specs of my laptop with the PC we identified that the PC had only windows 7 , not windows 7 service pack 1. After installing SP1 it started working.